# keypress event is not fired when we press enter key

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am facing a problem regarding to the `keypress` event. When I press the enter key then `keypress` event is not fired but it is working fine with the other keys.

Here is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        alert('hi');
        $("#ctl00_popupPageBody_txtFirstName,#ctl00_popupPageBody_txtLastName").keypress(function (e) {
            var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
            alert(code);
            if (code == 13) { //Enter keycode
                //Do something
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: remove the alerts and use `e.which` only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **keyup** event for this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ctl00_popupPageBody_txtFirstName,#ctl00_popupPageBody_txtLastName").keyup(function(e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            //Enter keycode //Do something 
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I disagree. A keystroke usually takes effect when the key is pressed, not when it is released. `keypress` is probably the correct event, and `keydown` is preferable to `keyup`.

Answer (score 0):

Use just [e.which](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) as its normalized across keys:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        alert('hi');
        $("#ctl00_popupPageBody_txtFirstName,#ctl00_popupPageBody_txtLastName").keypress(function (e) {
            var code = e.which; 
            alert(code);
            if (code === 13) { //Enter keycode
                e.preventDefault();
                //your code goes here
            }
        });
    });
```

Note: in my case I bind do .keydown