# JQuery Mobile Filter Enter Capture Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, keydown

I'm having an issue with Jquery mobile's Filterable Widget and tying a keydown listener to the search input to capture only the enter key.  Upon an initial search for a word, like 'Apple', and hit enter key, it works as expected (the results clear and the focus gets set back to the input).

But on only subsequent search attempts for a word, like 'Banana', the first letter of 'Banana' is not getting entered, its only displaying 'anana' because I believe the keydown listener is interfering with the first key being entered into the input box.  Please see the following example demonstrating this issue:

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/mczzzcd3/)

```js
$('#filter-input').keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) { //Enter keycode
    // Do something here
  /* yada yada yada*/
    
    // Now clear input and set focus back to input
    $(this).val('').trigger("keyup").focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<input data-type="search" id="filter-input" placeholder="Search">
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-filter="true" data-filter-reveal="true" data-input="#filter-input">
  <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all">Apple</a>
  <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all">Banana</a>
  <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all">Car</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please use the JSFiddle example as the stackoverflow one does not work correctly.

Comment: Your code works fine, see https://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/mczzzcd3/7/, your issue must be elsewhere in the `/* yada yada yada*/` code you dont show

Comment: you're not somehow filtering out capital letters, perhaps with a miss-written regex, are you?

Comment: First attempt works as expected, enter a search term and press enter key.  On second attempt, the first character of your word does not get entered into the input field, that is the issue I'm trying to fix.  Make sure you are pressing enter key on first attempt, second attempt after using enter key will experience the issue.

Comment: @Oh wait, I see what you mean, just a min

Comment: There has to be something going on with JQM; because if you comment out all of my JS (not even have the keydown listener) and hit the enter key while focused in the input box, the next key will not get displayed.  I just confirmed that this happens right on Jquery mobiles demo page!  [http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/filterable/](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/filterable/)  Try going to any input, hit enter key, then try to type... the first character you type is ignored and only subsequent characters are typed.

Comment: Yeah Im tracking it back now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so if you track the events through JQM, inside of `$.widget( "mobile.filterable", {});` you'll find this

```
// Prevent form submission
    _onKeyDown: function( event ) {
        if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.ENTER ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            this._preventKeyPress = true; // the culprit
        }
    },

    _onKeyPress: function( event ) {
        if ( this._preventKeyPress ) { // the check that fails
            event.preventDefault();
            this._preventKeyPress = false;// the solution
        }
    },
```

If you inspect the above  you'll see that `$.widget( "mobile.filterable", {});` has an internal detection of the `Enter` keydown and when it hears it, it sets `this._preventKeyPress = true;`, 3 guesses what that does.... yup ignores any further keypresses.

Presumably, this is done to stop you from changing the search string while the widget is processing the last search or something along those lines.

But, note that `_onKeyPress` sets  `this._preventKeyPress = false;` thus we can fix your issue with:

`$(this).val('').trigger("keypress").focus();`

#### [Working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/mczzzcd3/11/)

Comment: This does work in the jsFiddle, but when trying to add the same thing to my full code, it's not working for me... Is there any other method I can try to override or trick these keydown/keypress events from firing?

Comment: The trigger("keypress") isn't firing the keypress.  If I manually fire it from the console, it works, but in my code just like you have it, it doesn't work.

Comment: I found that if I change my listener from a keydown to a keyup, it works in my code along with your suggestion.  Got the idea from this: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/11521970/6002724](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11521970/6002724)

Comment: @Tim, That's weird, can you reproduce it in a jsFiddle? I cant imagine what might cause that except if you have other  libraries interfering with the event in your actual project

Comment: I tried adding an additional js library to jsFiddle that I'm using (jquery.tablesorter) but that did not affect your Working jsFiddle in any way... I'm very appreciative of your help!